# How to obtain Amanita Muscaria in California for brewing

Tags: fermentation

I just read an article about brewing with Amanita Muscaria. Does anyone know the best way to get the mushroom in California?

Answer (score 1):

Check with your local [mycological society](http://bayareamushrooms.org/california_clubs.html) in your area. If it grows wild near you. You can buy grow kits and try to grow it indoors. But the mycological society is probably your best bet for finding it wild or a supplier that you can get it from.